# Unable to click-iterate through elements using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Im trying to click-iterate through google-translate element but the code isnt working

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com.br/ShowUserReviews-g1-d8729164-r425802060-TAP_Portugal-World.html")
for i in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("entry"):
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

google_translate = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".googleTranslation .link")))

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(google_translate).click().perform()
driver.find_element_by_class_name("ui_close_x").click()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 600);")
```

=======ISSUE======
Its itertaing through the very first element only

---

Basically the code should show translation for each of the review in a popup, close that popup and then move to next review, translate etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com.br/ShowUserReviews-g1-d8729164-r425802060-TAP_Portugal-World.html")
gt= driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".googleTranslation>.link")
for i in gt:
    i.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("ui_close_x").click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

The above code will solve your purpose of clicking on each review google translate.
PS: in For loop i have placed the time.sleep() so that you can see the code action, if you want you can remote it

Comment: Sometimes the code is failing. For the link --> https://www.tripadvisor.com/Airline_Review-d8729164-Reviews-Cheap-Flights-TAP-Portugal#review_425811350, I selected portuguese comments and then ran your code [ gt=driver.find_elements.......] but after one translation Im getting this error :-----------> WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point (312.5, 10.100006103515625). Other element would receive the click: <li class="tabs_pers_item" id="TABS_TIPS" onclick="ta.plc_airline_detail_persistent_header_0_handlers.clickTab(this);"></li>

Comment: basiclly the problem is you are trying to change the lang while the page is loading.  Add these lines after driver.get will solve your problem     wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

langselection = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.sprite-date_picker-triangle")))
langselection.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='languageList']//li[normalize-space(.)='Portuguese first']").click()

Comment: posted it as seperate question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39951766/click-iteration-fails-in-selenium, pls post your solution there and ill mark your solution as resolved. Thanks