# click iteration fails in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Im trying to translate user comments from tripadvisor. So the scraper reads the link, then one by one iterates through each of the comments and translates them. But my code stops after translating the first comment itself.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.in/ShowUserReviews-g1-d8729164-r425811350-TAP_Portugal-World.html")
gt= driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".googleTranslation>.link")
for i in gt:
    i.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("ui_close_x").click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
url="https://www.tripadvisor.com/Airline_Review-d8729164-Reviews-Cheap-Flights-TAP-Portugal#REVIEWS"
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

langselction = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.sprite-date_picker-triangle")))
langselction.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='languageList']//li[normalize-space(.)='Portuguese first']").click()
gt= driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".googleTranslation>.link")
for i in gt:
    i.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("ui_close_x").click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Getting this error as soon as I run your code ----> "Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x0000000003BD5128>> ignored"  .   Then I ran the last 6 lines separately again , but the translation stopped after user "José C" comments.  This second error is --------> "WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point"

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome("path to chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")...provide proper path to chromedriver  of your machine

Comment: @shalini when I am running the above code its clicking on all the comments.

Comment: Im using driver = webdriver.Firefox()

Comment: after using this -----> driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");  Im unable to enter anything else in console. Its not taking any command

Comment: download chromedrive from this link http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.24/chromedriver_win32.zip and unzip it & provide path to unzipped location of "chromedriver.exe"

Comment: Thanks that worked but Im stuck with another issue now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971323/selenium-fails-to-iterate-on-elements

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same code of yours just increased the sleep time and list is getting traversed through the list and comments are also getting translated

Note: I tried the program on Firefox

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.in/ShowUserReviews-g1-d8729164-r425811350-TAP_Portugal-World.html")
gt= driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".googleTranslation>.link")
print(type(gt))
for i in gt:
    i.click()
    time.sleep(15)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("ui_close_x").click()
    time.sleep(15)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but Im facing another issue now -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971323/selenium-fails-to-iterate-on-elements